# creating Cloudformation Template fails: Resolution error: Trying to resolve() a Construct

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I try to create a Role with a policy that looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:oidc-provider/my-provider-domain.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "my-provider-domain.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:sub": [
                        "system:serviceaccount:account1",
                        "system:serviceaccount:account2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I created a java-Stack class file that looks like this:

```
public class TestStack extends Stack {

    public TestStack(Construct parent) {
        super(parent, "test-stack");

        String url = "https://my-provider-domain.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com";
        List<String> serviceAccounts = List.of("system:serviceaccount:account1", "system:serviceaccount:account2");
        String providerId = url.replace("https://", "");

        OpenIdConnectProvider provider = new OpenIdConnectProvider(this, providerId, OpenIdConnectProviderProps.builder()
                .url(url)
                .clientIds(List.of("sts.amazonaws.com"))
                .build());

        CfnJson condition = new CfnJson(this, Names.uniqueId(provider) + "sub", CfnJsonProps.builder()
                .value(Map.of(provider.getOpenIdConnectProviderIssuer() + ":sub", serviceAccounts))
                .build());

        OpenIdConnectPrincipal principal = new OpenIdConnectPrincipal(provider, Map.of("ForAnyValue:StringEquals", condition));

        Role role = new Role(this, "logshipperRole", RoleProps.builder()
                .assumedBy(principal)
                .build());

        PolicyStatement assumeRolePolicy = new PolicyStatement(PolicyStatementProps.builder()
                .actions(List.of("sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"))
                .effect(Effect.ALLOW)
                .principals(List.of(principal))
                .build());

        role.getAssumeRolePolicy().addStatements(assumeRolePolicy);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately running `cdk synth` doesn't work. When I run the command I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Trying to resolve() a Construct at /Resources/${Token[test-stack.logshipperRole.Resource.LogicalID.225]}/Properties/assumeRolePolicyDocument/Statement/0/Condition/ForAnyValue:StringEquals/node.
[ERROR] Object creation stack:
[ERROR]   at new PolicyDocument (/tmp/jsii-kernel-BSwRZj/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam/lib/policy-document.js:1:758)
[ERROR]   at createAssumeRolePolicy (/tmp/jsii-kernel-BSwRZj/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam/lib/role.js:1:10465)
[ERROR]   at new Role (/tmp/jsii-kernel-BSwRZj/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam/lib/role.js:1:1390)
[ERROR]   at /tmp/jsii-java-runtime13369413665972094812/lib/program.js:8420:58
[ERROR]   at Kernel._wrapSandboxCode (/tmp/jsii-java-runtime13369413665972094812/lib/program.js:8848:24)
[ERROR]   at Kernel._create (/tmp/jsii-java-runtime13369413665972094812/lib/program.js:8420:34)
[ERROR]   at Kernel.create (/tmp/jsii-java-runtime13369413665972094812/lib/program.js:8161:29)
[ERROR]   at KernelHost.processRequest (/tmp/jsii-java-runtime13369413665972094812/lib/program.js:9769:36)
[ERROR]   at KernelHost.run (/tmp/jsii-java-runtime13369413665972094812/lib/program.js:9732:22)
[ERROR]   at Immediate._onImmediate (/tmp/jsii-java-runtime13369413665972094812/lib/program.js:9733:46)
[ERROR]   at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)..
[ERROR]     at resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-BSwRZj/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/resolve.js:1:2787)
[ERROR]     at Object.resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-BSwRZj/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/resolve.js:1:1136)
[ERROR]     at resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-BSwRZj/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/resolve.js:1:2958)
[ERROR]     at Object.resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-BSwRZj/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/resolve.js:1:1136)
[ERROR]     at resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-BSwRZj/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/resolve.js:1:2958)
[ERROR]     at Object.resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-BSwRZj/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/resolve.js:1:1136)
[ERROR]     at resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-BSwRZj/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/resolve.js:1:2958)
[ERROR]     at Object.resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-BSwRZj/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/resolve.js:1:1136)
[ERROR]     at /tmp/jsii-kernel-BSwRZj/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/resolve.js:1:2522
[ERROR]     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

and I don't understand what I have done wrong. Why can't the cdk find the Construct (I guess it's the CfnJson that can't be resolved?!)

Comment: The problem seems to be that I use the same principal as assumedBy when creating the role and then as principal in the PolicyStatement. 

CDK seems to have a problems when it finds the same condition multiple times. When I add the condition to the PolicyStatement the template get created but with two statements (one with condition and one without)

Comment: is there a reason you're using cfnJson instead of PolicyDocument? You can generate a policy with an L2 construct instead of the cfn prefixed L1 construct and that slots into other L2 constructs easily.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/java/index.html?
software/amazon/awscdk/services/iam/PolicyDocument.html

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this correctly. In my opinion I can't replace the CfnJson with a PolicyDocument, because it's a Principal Condition, no Policy. I just want a Role with the a Policy like provided. Unfortunately it's required to pass a principal when creating a Role. When adding a AssumeRolePolicy this assumeBy-Principal should be merged with the given policy and result in the wanted Document. If I add the condition to the Policy instead of the principal a cloud formation template is generated, but with two different actions.